# MySQL charset issue

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure exactly why this happened, but I'm assuming it was an dump and import.  The db is full of characters like â€” for commas and such.  I've tried various solutions on the web, but nothing seems to work.  I've verified that the html header specifies utf8.

Any ideas on how I can get the entire db back to normal characters?

Answer (score 0):

Had your dumpfile set encoding to utf8? This could be the problem

Comment: I tried dumping with --default-character-set utf8 and also importing with the --default-character-set=utf8 and no change.

Comment: Did you check the collation of the database's tables?